# LESS stylesheet(update class B when class A hovers)

Tags: css, web, less

I have one div "classA" that contains inside one sprite element of classB. I need to develop the LESS code  that changes attributes of classB when I hover classA. the css would be like:

classA:hover classB{
     etc
}

but no idea how to make this connection in LESS.

artdias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use indentation LESS feature:

```
.classA:hover {
    /* Style for "hovered" classA */
    .classB {
        /* Style for .classB when classA is "hovered" */
    }
}
```

And if you want to use another fantastic LESS feature:

```
.classA {
    /* Style for "normal" classA */
    &:hover {
        /* Style for "hovered" classA */
        .classB {
            /* Style for classB when classA is "hovered" */
            /* classB elements are contained within the classA */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this meets the spec of the question, but just wanted to make it clear to others reading this that the altered classB styles will only apply to the elements contained within the hovered classA element.  The output is

    .classA:hover .classB { /* Style for classB when classA is hovered */}